# I'm using the PayPal API and I want the resulting payment data to be saved in my database

Tags: php, paypal

My problem is that I try to save the JSON data that PayPal returns when making the payment and save it in a MySQL database but the insert is not done.

Here's the code of the button

```
<div class="prenda">
            <span>
                Tallas
            </span>
            <form class="comprarprenda" action="RegistrarCompra.php" method="post">
                <input class="elegirtalla" type="radio" name="talla" id="XS" value="XS" required>
                <input class="elegirtalla" type="radio" name="talla" id="S" value="S">
                <input class="elegirtalla" type="radio" name="talla" id="M" value="M">
                <input class="elegirtalla" type="radio" name="talla" id="L" value="L">
                <input class="elegirtalla" type="radio" name="talla" id="XL" value="XL">
                <p>
                    <button class="comprar" type="submit" value="comprar" name="botons">
                        Comprar
                    </button>

                    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

                    <script>

                        try {
                            var costo = 0;
                            const reqS = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
                            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
                            function Comentarios()
                            {
                                reqS.onload = function ShowComents(){
                                var co =  reqS.responseText;
                                costo = co;
                                alert(costo);
                            }
                                reqS.open("GET", "phpapi.php?");
                                reqS.send();
    
                            }, false);
                            
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }

                        try {
                            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
    
    
                            paypal.Buttons({
                                style:{
                                    layout: 'horizontal',
                                    color:  'silver',
                                    shape:  'pill',
                                    tagline: 'false',
                                    label:  'paypal'
                                },
                                createOrder: function(data, actions)
                                {
                                    return actions.order.create({
                                        purchase_units: [{
                                            amount: {
                                                value: costo
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    });
                                },
                                onApprove: function(data, actions)
                                {
                                        let url = 'GetDatosCompra.php'
                                    actions.order.capture().then(function(detalles)
                                    {
                                        console.log(detalles);
                                        alert("Pago realizado");
                                        //window.location.href="";
                                        return fetch(url,
                                        {
                                            method: 'post',
                                            headers: 
                                            {
                                                'content-type': 'application/json'
                                            },
                                            body: JSON.stringify(
                                                {
                                                        detalles: detalles
                                                }
                                            )
                                        });
                                    });
                                },

                                onCancel: function(data)
                                {
                                    alert("Pago cancelado");
                                    console.log(data);
                                },
                                onError: function (err) 
                                {
                                    alert("Ha sucedido un error, intente de nuevo");
                                }
                            }).render('#paypal-button-container'), false);
                            
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    </script>

                    <button class="alcarrito" type="submit" value="carrito" name="botons">
                        <abbr title="Añadir al carrito de compras">
                            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/cadivie/image/upload/v1653571538/carritodecompras_pzica7.png">

                        </abbr>
                    </button>
                    <button class="guardarenlista" type="submit" value="listadeseos" name="botons">
                        <abbr title="Añadir a lista de deseos">
                            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/cadivie/image/upload/v1653571538/bookmark_ayho2g.png">

                        </abbr>
            </button>
                </p>            

            </form>
            
        </div>
```

here's the code for the query

```
<?php

session_start();
include "database.php";
$id_us = $_SESSION["id_us"];
$id_producto = $_SESSION['id_p'];



$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$datos = json_decode($json, true);

if(is_array($datos))
{
    $id_transaccion = $datos['detalles']['id'];
    $precio = $datos['detalles']['purchase_units'][0]['amount']['value'];
    $estado = $datos['detalles']['status'];
    $fecha = $datos['detalles']['update_time'];
    $fecha_db = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fecha));
    $email = $datos['detalles']['payer']['email_address'];
    $id_cliente = $datos['detalles']['payer']['payer_id'];

    
    echo "<script> alert('$id_us') </script>"; 
    echo "<script> alert('$id_producto') </script>"; 
    echo "<script> alert('$id_transaccion') </script>"; 
    echo "<script> alert('$estado') </script>"; 
    echo "<script> alert('$email') </script>"; 
    echo "<script> alert('$id_cliente') </script>"; 
    echo "<script> alert('$precio') </script>"; 
    echo "<script> alert('$fecha_db') </script>"; 
    echo $id_us; 
    echo $id_producto;
    echo $id_transaccion;
    echo $estado;
    echo $email;
    echo $id_cliente;
    echo $precio;
    echo $fecha_db;

    $ingreso = "INSERT INTO comprado (id_usuario, id_producto, id_transaccion, estado, email, id_cliente, precio, fecha_historial) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $sql->execute([$id_us, $id_producto, $id_transaccion, $estado, $email, $id_cliente, $precio, $fecha_db]);
    
    $id_historial = $con->lastInsertId();
}


?>
```

I put echo so I can see the value of the variables but nothing happens

with this code I get the id of the product from the database

```
 <?PHP

session_start();

include "database.php";
$id = $_SESSION['id_p'];

    $query = "SELECT * from productos WHERE id_producto = '$id'";     // Esta linea hace la consulta
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query); 

    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        echo $registro['precio'];
}

?>
```

And this is my database

[database fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUUe7.png)

Answer (score 0):

> actions.order.capture()

Do *not* use client-side [JS SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/) create and capture functions if you are going to write the result to a database. That is not a robust integration pattern. These functions are only for very simple use cases.

Instead, follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You can use Checkout-PHP-SDK for your routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and can then store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)